# Change computer Apple TV uses to connect to iTunes

Tags: appletv

I have the newest version of Apple TV. Firmware is up to date.

I set it up in the apartment I used to share with my girlfriend until about a week ago when I moved away for school. After I left, she found herself not only without companionship but also unable to access Netflix or the iTunes store.

I'm guessing this is because I set up the Apple TV using *my* mac, which is no longer in the apartment with the Apple TV. Assuming this is the case, I'm wondering: is resetting the Apple TV and going through the setup process again the best way for her to "associate" *her* mac with the Apple TV? Or is there an easy way to do this that won't wipe out all of the configurations we've made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Apple TV:

1. Go to Settings > Computers
2. Turn off Home Sharing
3. Turn on Home Sharing (it will ask if you want to use your Apple ID or connect using a different one)
4. Select the option to connect using another account
5. Have her enter *her* Apple ID and password in

Of course for this to work, she will have to enable Home Sharing on iTunes on her Mac. For directions, [see Apple's guide on setting up Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4620).

As for Netflix, you should just be able to log out and log in with a different account.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the network connection is functioning properly.  I agree with Q. Sheets' answer about resetting Home Sharing, but that should only affect iTunes/Store related items.  If Netflix isn't working, it's more likely a network problem as she should still be able to use your Netflix login.

Try YouTube or some other Internet app to make sure the network is functioning.